Trying to find title of this movie I saw 20 years ago
The movie is set in the pacific northwest. The scenes are lonely remote highway, wooded forest:

The heroine is an athletic, young woman with dark hair. She somehow was able to track a serial kidnapper, and followed him to his house in the woods. 
She found a young girl, dressed up like a doll, who was kept prisoner in a cage in a basement. She frees the girl, but was not able to rescue others, that were also held captive. The kidnapper is killed. 
The heroine adopted the young girl.
It felt like a Michael Mann movie, similar to Manhunter, probably made late 80's to mid 90's. I saw this movie 20 years ago.


Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Marked it as a duplicate of an old question. If that's not the right answer, please let me know.

The ANSWER being the same does not make the QUESTION a duplicate.
